# How “logic-based symbolic reasoning” and “ontology” are related?

Tags: semantics, reasoning, ontologies

I have a basic understanding of knowledge representation systems, semantic networks and ontologies. But I can not relate my understanding to the reasoning.

How the **reasoning** is applied on ontologies and semantic networks?